# Best Way to implement JWT Authentication in Angular(Client Side) without Using Local Storage?

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I was trying to use JWT token for angular Authentication in the client side. I can't see a proper implementation for storing jwt token other than local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with localStorage. The token is being stored on the client side anyway so no matter how you store it the user will be able to access the token (assuming that is what you're trying to prevent). Localstorage is fast, simple and easy to use, so there is no reason not to use it. If you store the JWT in a cookie the user can still access the cookie with the developer tools in their browser to access it.

[Security through obscurity is not security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity#Criticism)

Comment: I may add that even though the user can see the cookie it won't be able to access it in any way. Only delete using developers tools. And cookies are way securer in terms of XSS!

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you have to have in mind that if you are using SPAs and communicate with a pure stateless API or you’re making HTTP requests to multiple backends or API is used in mobile apps as well and it requires the "Authorization Bearer xxx" header, it’s convenient to have your JWT in localStorage instead.

Otherwise When a user logs into your website, create a session identifier for them and store it in a somewhat signed cookie, look up for "how to create a user session using cookies".